# newbie problems with a console.log in a function

Tags: javascript

I want to get the output of the parameter in a `console.log`. It's a test I'm trying to understand what the content of the display parameter is.

```
    1. setWidgetAndRssDisplay("block")
    2. setWidgetAndRssDisplay("none")
    3. setWidgetAndRssDisplay("cooking")

    setWidgetAndRssDisplay: function(display) {
        console.log(display)
    },
```

This is the actual function:

```
setWidgetAndRssDisplay: function(display) {
       widgetDiv.style.display = display;
       rssWrapper.style.display = display;
},
```

What i'm trying to do, is to understand how the function sets the correct display property (block ,none) that's why i tried to get a console.log output of the display parameter

Comment: What is your issue ?

Comment: What errors are you getting? Is this function part of an object, otherwise the syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get only inline style value by `.style` object of element.
By `window.getComputedStyle` you can get css styles of element

```js
var widgetDiv = document.getElementById('widget');
var rssWrapper = document.getElementById('rssWrapper');
var widgetInlineDiv = document.getElementById('widgetInline');
var rssWrapperInline = document.getElementById('rssWrapperInline');
var setWidgetAndRssDisplay = function(display) {
  console.log('Display value:',display);
};
setWidgetAndRssDisplay(widgetDiv.style.display);
setWidgetAndRssDisplay(rssWrapper.style.display);
setWidgetAndRssDisplay(widgetInline.style.display);
setWidgetAndRssDisplay(rssWrapperInline.style.display);
setWidgetAndRssDisplay(window.getComputedStyle(widgetDiv,null).getPropertyValue("display"));
setWidgetAndRssDisplay(window.getComputedStyle(rssWrapper,null).getPropertyValue("display"));
```

```css
#rssWrapper{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="widget">Widget</div>
<div id="rssWrapper">rss wrapper</div>
<div id="widgetInline" style="display:none">Widget Inline Style</div>
<div id="rssWrapperInline" style="display:block">rss wrapper inline style</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

please write more info and errors i think this is work

```js
    var setWidgetAndRssDisplay = function(display) {
        console.log(display)
    }

    setWidgetAndRssDisplay("block")
    setWidgetAndRssDisplay("none")
    setWidgetAndRssDisplay("cooking")
```

because this is object syntax

```
setWidgetAndRssDisplay: function(display) {
    console.log(display)
},
```

and moving defination up because of hoisting

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting

or you can use function defination also work

```js
    setWidgetAndRssDisplay("block")
    setWidgetAndRssDisplay("none")
    setWidgetAndRssDisplay("cooking")
    
    function setWidgetAndRssDisplay(display) {
        console.log(display)
    }
```

Comment: Asking for more info on a question should be done in a comment and not an answer

Comment: Can you recommend me a good online editor where i can try this out? (where i can see also the console output)

Comment: i tried your link out, but i dont see any output on the right half of the window

Comment: @mutulica10 please use developer console